# お腹 - why【なか】reading is missing from dictionaries?

Tags: kanji, readings

Why is that when I search for:
https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8A%E8%85%B9

【なか】reading is there, but in entry for kanji itself, it is clearly missing:
https://jisho.org/search/%E8%85%B9%20%23kanji

I've checked also in Kodansha Kanji Learner’s Dictionary, 2nd Edition (Jack Halpern), but to no avail.

Is is just this specific case, or are there more like that? If so, what is the rule of thumb to deal with that?

Comment: Yes. Wow, this is embarrassing. I've should have found this by myself... thank you.

Comment: FWIW, sometimes the JA Wiktionary can be useful. Here's [their entry for 腹](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%85%B9), which includes the なか reading as 「常用【じょうよう】漢字表【かんじひょう】外【がい】」 ("off the Jōyō kanji chart", i.e. "non-Jōyō reading").